# Отображение изображения в html теге

Tags: java, servlet

Допустим есть некий код :

```
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(getPageWithImage(imagePath));
    out.close();
```

Внутри метода `getPageWithImage`, мы генерируем `html` разметку, и в тег `img` кладем наше изображение, чей путь мы передали в метод.

Вопрос : как мне отобразить? Путь который будет указан в `html` разметке будет локальный : `C:/example/images.` Как сделать путь релевантным относительно к сервлету `localhost:8080/servlet/img.png` ?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать путь в виде:

```
C:\\example\\images\\ + имя картинки (image.png)
```

Или же в проекте создать папку RESOURCES(ресурсы) хранить все картинки там тогда нужно будет только указать **ИМЯ файла с расширением** и все. **Так будет лучше**.

Что касается

```
localhost:8080/servlet/img.png
```

Пока что не чего сказать.